# Combinatorial proof for a Catalan number identity with an alternating sum.

Tags: inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs, catalan-numbers, formal-power-series, integer-sequences

Define the function

$$ T_a(x) := 1/(a + 1/x). \tag1 $$

It is easy to check that

$$ T_{a+b}(x) = T_a (T_b(x)). \tag2 $$

Specialize this equality to get

$$ x = T_ 0(x) = T_ 1(T_{-1}(x)) = T_{-1}(T_ 1(x)). \tag3 $$

Equivalently, this implies that

$$ z = 1/(-1 + 1/y) \;\; \text{iff} \;\;
 y = 1/(1 + 1/z) \;\; \text{iff} \;\; z - y = y\,z. \tag4 $$

Expand, using formal power series to get

$$ z\!=\!y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + \cdots  \;\; \text{iff}
 \;\; y\!=\!z - z^2 + z^3 - z^4 + \cdots. \tag5 $$

Introduce the generating function of
[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

$$ c(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n = 1 + x + 2x^2 + 5x^3 + \cdots. \
\tag6 $$

The usual well-known recurrence for Catalan numbers is

$$ C_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n C_k C_ {n-k} \tag7 $$

with many direct combinatorial interpretations. Expressed in terms
of the generating function $\,c (x)\,$ this is equivalent to

$$ c(x) = 1 + x\,c (x)^2 = 1 + (c(x) x) c(x). \tag8 $$

This is also algebraically equivalent to

$$ (c(x)-1) = (c(x)x) + (c(x)x)(c(x)-1). \tag9 $$

Iterating this equality to the limit produces the infinite series equation

$$ (c(x)-1) = (c(x)x) + (c(x)x)^2 + (c(x)x)^3 + \cdots. \tag{10} $$

This has direct combinatorial interpretations also. For example,
every Dyck word splits uniquely into nonempty irreducible Dyck words
each of which uniquely corresponds to a Dyck word after removing the
first and last letters.

Apply equation $(5)$ to this equation to get

$$ (c(x)x) = (c(x)-1) - (c(x)-1)^2 + (c(x)-1)^3 - \cdots. \tag{11} $$

The question is how to prove this combinatorially. A difficulty is
how to interpret the alternating sum combinatorially. Perhaps one way
is to use
[inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

It would be sufficient to find a combinatorial proof of equation
$(5)$ where both $\,y\,$ and $\,z\,$ are formal power series in
$\,x\,$ with constant term $0$. More explicitly,

$$ y = a_1x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots \;\; \text{ and }
\;\; z = b_1x + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3 + \cdots. \tag{12} $$

Use equation $(5)$ to get

$$ b_1 = a_1,\;\; b_2 = a_1^2 + a_2, \;\;
 b_3 = a_1^3 + 2a_1a_2 + a_3, \;\; \dots \tag{13} $$

whose combinatorial interpretation is a generalization of the one
for equation $(10)$ with Dyck words. That is, $\,b_n\,$ represents
all Dyck words of length $\,2n\,$ while $\,a_n\,$ represents all
irreducible Dyck words of length $\,2n.\,$

Also use equation $(5)$ to get

$$ a_1 = b_1,\;\; a_2 = -b_1^2 + b_2, \;\;
 a_3 = b_1^3 - 2b_1b_2 + b_3, \;\; \dots \tag{14} $$

whose combinatorial interpretation would be a generalization of
equation $(11)$ but is currently unknown to me. A combinatorial
proof would be nice to know. Does anyone know?

Comment: Isn't this just straightforward inclusion-exclusion on number of returns?  The LHS counts paths with no returns directly, the RHS is inclusion-exclusion to count paths with no returns.

Comment: @JBL LHS of what? What path returns?

Comment: LHS of (11).  $c(x)$ is the generating function for Dyck paths.  A return in a Dyck path is a moment when it touches the bounding line (either the line $y = x$, if you think Dyck paths are lattice grid paths, or the $x$-axis, if you think Dyck paths have steps $(1, 1)$ and $(1, -1)$).  (In terms of Dyck words, this is a prefix that is itself a Dyck word.)  $xc(x)$ is the generating function for Dyck paths / words with no returns other than the trivial one (what you call "irreducible").

Comment: @JBL Please submit that as an answer. Does it work for (14) also?

Comment: I am away from my computer but I will write it up better this afternoon some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question observes, each Dyck word decomposes uniquely as a concatenation of nontrivial irreducible Dyck words; say that a concatenation of $\ell$ irreducible Dyck words has $\ell - 1$ *returns*.  $xc(x)$ is the gf for irreducible Dyck words.  $c(x) - 1$ is the gf for nontrivial Dyck words.  $(c(x) - 1)^k$ is the gf for concatenations of $k$ Dyck words.  Therefore, each a Dyck word $D$ with exactly $m$ returns is counted in $(c(x) - 1)^k$ precisely $\binom{m}{k - 1}$ times.  Taking the signs into account, this means $D$ is counted $\sum_k (-1)^k \binom{m}{k - 1}$ times on the right side of (11); this is $0$ if $m > 0$ and is $1$ if $m = 0$, i.e., if $D$ is irreducible.

(None of this has anything to do with the fact that $c(x)$ is the GF for Dyck words specifically; the same combinatorics governs the behavior of (4) and (5) in general, where $y$ is the gf for irreducibles and $z$ is the gf for concatenations of irreducibles.)